# how to change the font color of just one word in excel cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change the font colour of specific words, say I want to change the colour of "Funding" to red. Just like this
[image]
*String content*

```
Subject to the Availability of Funding and Army Priorities: Although the Government intends to award one follow-on Production award during Fiscal Year (FY) 2023 (FY23), Offerors are advised that due to internal Government considerations, there could be a Funding significant delay between the conclusion of the Prototype OTA activities and the award of a follow-on Production Agreement or Contract. Further, the Government at its sole discretion reserves the right not to proceed Funding into production.
```

But is it possible to automate this using VBA? the recorded VBA code is as

```
With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=31).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=32, Length:=7).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=39, Length:=217).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
```

Is not a great solution. I have to check from where the word starts and then change the word colour.

I also tried to use find and replace but when using it the whole-cell colour changes and not just the word "Funding"

Comment: Please, edit your question and paste the string as text, not a picture. If somebody wants helping and using your string it shouldn't be necessary to write it just looking to a picture...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub testWordFontColorChange()
   Dim x As String, firstChar As Long, lastChar As Long, strSearch As String

   x = ActiveCell.Value
   strSearch = "Funding"
   
   firstChar = InStr(x, strSearch)
   If firstChar = 0 Then _
      MsgBox "The character """ & strSearch & """ could not be found...": Exit Sub
    ActiveCell.Characters(firstChar, Len(strSearch)).Font.color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

Please, test the next code, able to change font color for all occurrences:

```
Sub testWordFontColorChangeMultiple()
   Dim x As String, firstChar As Long, lastChar As Long, strSearch As String

   x = ActiveCell.Value
   strSearch = "Funding"
   firstChar = InStr(x, strSearch)
   If firstChar = 0 Then _
           MsgBox "The character """ & strSearch & """ could not be found...": Exit Sub
           
   Do While firstChar > 0
         ActiveCell.Characters(firstChar, Len(strSearch)).Font.color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
         firstChar = InStr(firstChar + 1, x, strSearch)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: This can't be used if the same word is repeated in the string right?

Comment: @Derik0003 If you do not say about that, of course, not. Otherwise, another piece of code can be written...

Comment: Please help. I require that. Sorry for not saying that before

Comment: @Derik0003 But I cannot see such a repeated word in the example you posted, neither...

Comment: Oh, I just added it now.

Comment: @Derik0003 OK. Plese, test the code posted after "**Edited**:" and send some feedback

Comment: Thank you so much. Marked the answer.